# How to get the output of a Python subprocess and terminate it afterwards?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I want to get the output of my subprocess. As it runs indefinitely I want to terminate it when certain conditions are fulfilled.

When I start the subprocess by using `check_output`, I get the output but no handle to terminate the process:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```

When I start the subprocess by using `Popen` or `run`, I get a handle to terminate the process, but no output.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

How can I get both?

Comment: when can you know that you've got the full process output? when the process terminates. So no need to terminate it manually. Just wait for it to end. I don't understand your question. You probably want to read a few lines and terminate right?

Comment: I neither assume a process that ends by itself, nor do I assume "full process output". The condition on which the process shall be terminated is independent of the process output. I want to read the output and terminate whenever I like to.

Comment: if "whenever I like to" is linked to what is in the output, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when can you know that you've got the full process output? when the process terminates. So no need to terminate it manually. Just wait for it to end, and using `check_output` is the way.

Now if you want to wait for a given pattern to appear, *then* terminate, now that's something else. Just read line by line and if some pattern matches, break the loop and end the process

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid) # add stderr=subprocess.PIPE) to merge output & error
for line in p.stdout:
   if b"some string" in line:  # output is binary
       break
p.kill() # or p.terminate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to tell `Popen` you want to read the standard output, but it can be a little tricky.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    chunk = p.stdout.read(1024)  # this will hang forever if there's nothing to read
p.terminate()
```

Comment: "this will hang forever if there's nothing to read": well, this will hang forever period because you have an infinite loop. Add `if not chunk: break` so it terminates when process ends.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("ls -a", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print((p.stdout.read()))
if p.stdout.read() or p.stderr.read():
    p.terminate()
```

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think this works. `if p.stdout or p.stderr` is always true. Those are file handles.

Comment: also `print(p.stdout)` doesn't print the output unless you perform `read()` on it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i already update the code check it now i think i fixed the problem by reading the data inside the stdout file

Comment: not `if p.stdout.read() or p.stderr.read()` is strange. The first term is always false (because was already read the line above) and the other one is either empty or not but it's not what OP asked.